# integers solution (x,y)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many tuple (x,y) positive integer solution to

$13/x^2 + 1996/y^2 = 2/1997$

I've done many algebraic manipulation to the equation but can't find any thing.

How I find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  2 x^2 y^2 = 1996 \cdot 1997 x^2 + 13 \cdot 1997 y^2,$$
$$  2 x^2 y^2 - 1996 \cdot 1997 x^2 - 13 \cdot 1997 y^2 = 0,$$
$$  4 x^2 y^2 - 2 \cdot 1996 \cdot 1997 x^2 - 2 \cdot 13 \cdot 1997 y^2 = 0,$$
$$ ( 2 x^2 - 13 \cdot 1997) ( 2 y^2 - 1996 \cdot 1997 ) = 13 \cdot 1996 \cdot 1997^2 = 2^2 \cdot  13 \cdot 499 \cdot 1997^2$$